# Python thread blocking further execution

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been trying to write a python script that initiates a thread to listen on a socket and send HTTP data to another application to be launched by the same program. There is a requirement for the socket server to be running prior to executing the application. However, the thread running the socket server blocks further execution of the program and it freezes where it is listening. Putting some dummy code.

In module 1:

```
def runServer(Port, Host, q):
    HTTPServerObj = HTTPServer((Host, Port), RequestHandler)
    HTTPServerObj.handle_request()
    HTTPServerObj.server_close()
    q.put((True, {'messageDoNotDuplicate': 'Data sent successfully by the server'}))

class SpoofHTTPServer(object):
    def runServerThread(self):
        q = Queue.Queue()
        serverThread=Thread(target=runServer, args=(self.Port, self.Host, q))
        serverThread.daemon=True
        serverThread.start()
        result = q.get()
        print result
        return result
```

In module 2:

```
from module1 import SpoofHTTPServer

spoofHTTPServer = SpoofHTTPServer()
result = spoofHTTPServer.runServerThread()
rc = myApp.start()
```

The myApp.start() never gets executed as the thread is blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the method that blocks execution is not the thread but `q.get()`. It will listen to the `Queue` until an item is available, but since it's executed before running the client application nothing ever gets posted into the queue. Maybe you should `return q` instead and listen to the queue in module 2 after calling `myApp.start()`?

Comment: According to http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get it looks like one can use get(False) or get_nowait() for non-blocking call, if that's the desired behavior.

Comment: @woozyking: Yes, but in this case it will always raise the `Empty` exception because the code that inserts data into the queue can not have been executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you from Python 3. Make a connection to `('localhost', 8080)` to see it work.

```
import queue as Queue
from threading import Thread
from http.server import HTTPServer
from socketserver import BaseRequestHandler as RequestHandler

def runServer(Port, Host, q):
    HTTPServerObj = HTTPServer((Host, Port), RequestHandler)
    HTTPServerObj.handle_request()
    HTTPServerObj.server_close()
    q.put((True, {'messageDoNotDuplicate':
                  'Data sent successfully by the server'}))

class SpoofHTTPServer(object):

    Port = 8080
    Host = ''

    def runServerThread(self):
        q = Queue.Queue()
        serverThread=Thread(target=runServer, args=(self.Port, self.Host, q))
        serverThread.daemon=True
        serverThread.start()
        result = q.get()
        print(result)
        return result

spoofHTTPServer = SpoofHTTPServer()
result = spoofHTTPServer.runServerThread()
##rc = myApp.start()
```

Comment: I am doing it, just not mentioned in the code I posted though. Sorry about that. :(